# Find and replace all same files between 2 directories

Tags: bash, shell-script, files, rm, file-copy

I want to find all files in `dir1` having corresponding same file names in `dir2`, and replace them with the files from `dir2`.

For example:

```
dir1: first.txt second.txt
dir2: third.txt first.txt
```

So I want to remove from `dir1` the old `first.txt` file and replace it with `first.txt` from `dir2`.

How to achieve this using Bash terminal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, there's a single command that does exactly what you're asking.

```
rsync -av --existing dir2/ dir1/
```

This will recursively copy the files from dir2 into dir1 only if the file already exists in dir1.

The `-av` options are the options you'll usually use for copying files using rsync.

The `--existing` option tells `rsync` to skip creating new files on receiver.

You must have the trailing slash on dir2/ on the command line because `rsync` behaves differently than most commands in the slash has a meaning to rsync.

`rsync` can also be used over the network similar to `scp`.

`rsync` can handle many other types of file synchronization, updating, and backup tasks.

Comment: Thanks, Can you please help with this sub question: How can I dlete from`dir1` all duplicate files?

Comment: Please post another question and describe as clearly as possible what you want to accomplish with examples, like you did on this question.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/240466/find-and-delete-all-same-files-between-2-dirs

Answer (score 1):

rsync can do this with the `--existing` option:

`rsync -v --existing dir2/* dir1/`